# iPhone 5 corrupt photos

Tags: ios, photos, iphone, photos.app

I have this issue with recently purchased iPhone 5, 16 GB, iOS 7.0.4. The original issue was with the battery dying a way too fast (would go down from a little over 90% to just under 70% while using the phone for about 10 minute navigation trip). After I brought it to the Apple Store, I was told it's not the battery, but rather to OS was corrupted and it causing the battery to drain. The fix is very simple, a restore to the factory default.

However, that's where I ran into issues. We have some photos on that iPhone we want to preserve, so I tried coping them over to my Windows 7 laptop using explorer (direct access to DCIM folder), using Windows picture export future as well as iexplorer software and Picasa to no real luck.

Now I should add that not all pictures are affected, just the ones that were transferred from the iPhone 4s. The pictures, taken by this phone, were copied with no issues.

Is there anything I can do to get those pictures off?

**Update 4.II.2014 @ 9.50**

I am sorry, I should have also mentioned what else, we have tried.  We tried installing both Dropbox and Google Drive apps in the hope we could copy pictures that way, it works on some, but both get stuck on a *picture x* and the app crashes.  When we go back into the app, it just keeps loading.

We also tried emailing the pictures, but that doesn't work (at least on the pictures pre-iPhone 5).

**Update 5.II.2014 @ 11.30**

Another, quick add to the description, any pre-iPhone 5 pictures (the ones that were transferred from iPhone 4s) crash upon opening in the iPhone (so we can't really view them in full screen).

Comment: Do you have a web (Gmail? iCloud?) email account? Try emailing the photos to yourself and downloading them from your email.

Comment: We tried that with one or twp and I believe that worked, but we are talking about 100+ photos...  So we'll need something more than just emailing them.  iCould has space limit and normally has just backups, which we were told at the Apple Store not to restore from, because it'll like to contain corrupt data.

Comment: Actually, a correction, email it didn't work, however, editing some photos and emailing them worked, but it worked for some, but not others.

Comment: Another method of getting photos off the device would be to install Dropbox and use its uploader to select the photos off of your device.

Comment: @Todd Tried that too, along side with google drive.

Comment: What about taking screenshots of the photos when you display them in the Photos app? To do that, display the photo and then press the home and power button at the same time. You might lose some resolution, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @Todd I am glad you are asking those question, because, I'll need to add more to the description. The pre-iPhone 5 pictures, when opened come up and then crash (disappear), so that won't really work.

Comment: As my final Hail Mary, head back to the Apple Store and connect your phone to a Mac there. Open up Image Capture and see if you can retrieve the photos.  I doubt it'd do anything you're not already doing by directly accessing the DCIM folder, but maybe? And if not, I think you're just not going to get them back.

Comment: @Todd You know that's a great idea! Thank you! I might not do it at the Apple store (they told, we can't really hook up the phone to their precious Macs, I swear they are worse then Microsoft, when it comes to things like that), but I have a community college nearby with a pure Mac lab, so that might work out a little better anyway.

Comment: Sounds Bad, like they have never been correct imported from iPhone 4

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to get your pictures? If not try Iexplorer. It shows all content on the phone and you can easily export the entire library.